# Will installing IRkernel via CRAN work in my conda environment?

Tags: windows-10, jupyter-notebook, rstudio, conda, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to set up an R kernel to work in Jupyter Notebook and Jupyter Lab.

I have miniconda3 installed and when I `activate base` environment,

then type
 `jupyter-kernelspec list` I see

`python3    C:/path/to/miniconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3`

I want the R kernel so I can use it in Jupyter Lab and Jupyter Notebook.

I already have Rstudio installed. Is there a difference if I install the IRkernel to the kernels directory above via CRAN in Rstudio or fork it from github (assuming I can find it) and then clone it to the kernels directory?

Is this what I need to do or is possible that all I need to do is alter some variable in my environment PATH?

If download/install it via CRAN in Rstudio is that kernel going to be available in my `(base)` environment?

Answer (score 1):

If R is installed outside Conda (more common), then [install through CRAN](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel#installation).

If R is installed in a Conda env (less common), then follow [the `nb_conda_kernels` instructions](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels#installation).

Comment: I installed R and Rstudio before I installed conda, so if I understand this correctly then I should install through CRAN. My new question is, do I need to specify that `IRkernel` is installed to the kernels directory above? Or can I just open Rstudio > Packages >  Install > IRkernel & install to library: path/to/[default] and check dependencies?`


What I'm asking is, do I need to specify where `IRkernel` gets installed to?